# django form save can't be used update a model instance?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using django 1.8.4

djanog.forms.models.BaseModelForm.save reads as following

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    """
    Saves this ``form``'s cleaned_data into model instance
    ``self.instance``.

    If commit=True, then the changes to ``instance`` will be saved to the
    database. Returns ``instance``.
    """
    if self.instance.pk is None:
        fail_message = 'created'
    else:
        fail_message = 'changed'
    return save_instance(self, self.instance, self._meta.fields,
                         fail_message, commit, self._meta.exclude,
                         construct=False)
```

and `save_instance`  has this..

```
def save_instance(form, instance, fields=None, fail_message='saved',
                  commit=True, exclude=None, construct=True):
    """
    Saves bound Form ``form``'s cleaned_data into model instance ``instance``.

    If commit=True, then the changes to ``instance`` will be saved to the
    database. Returns ``instance``.

    If construct=False, assume ``instance`` has already been constructed and
    just needs to be saved.
    """
    if construct:
        instance = construct_instance(form, instance, fields, exclude)
```

Basically, the above code (save_instance) updates the instance only when `construct = True`, but django code passes `construct = False` all the time.

Is this a bug in 1.8.4? :(

I just checked the code remains same until 1.8.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `construct_instance` method is called in `BaseModelForm._post_clean`:

```
# BaseModelForm._post_clean()
# Update the model instance with self.cleaned_data.
self.instance = construct_instance(self, self.instance, opts.fields, construct_instance_exclude)
```

When this function is called, your "instance" will be updated with form data.

Note that `_post_clean` is called as part of `BaseForm.full_clean`, and is usually called indirectly by `is_valid`. This means that if you don't validate your form, calling save method will either fail with a new instance, or fail to update an old instance.

Comment: Thanks for pointing. I overrided one of the field and didn't put that field in `Meta.fields` and construct_instance skipped the field.